# Сравнение значений

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть множество значений которые изменяются со временем. Если значение достигает определенного критического значения (у каждого оно свое), то нужно отобразить информационное окно (`MessageBox`). То есть одновременно может быть открыто `N` таких окон. Пока открыто хотя бы одно из информационных окон, основное окно должно быть заблокировано. После закрытия информационного окна новое может быть открыто не ранее чем через 5 минут.

На текущий момент есть не рабочая версия, запускается по таймеру.

```
private async void AlarmMaxAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        if (IoDev.NumericC01RoiOil.Value >= 10)
        {
            if (Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show("Бла", "Внимание!!!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error) == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
               await Task.Delay(50000);
            }
        }

        if (IoDev.NumericC02RoiOil.Value >= 100)
        {
            if (Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show("Бла бла", "Внимание!!!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error) == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
               await Task.Delay(50000);
            }
        }

        if (IoDev.NumericC03RoiOil.Value >= 1000)
        {
            if (Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show("Бла бла бла", "Внимание!!!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error) == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
               await Task.Delay(50000);
            }
        }

   ........

}
```

Comment: Менять код объекта `IoDev` есть возможность?

Comment: А если там будет миллиард таких значений, для каждого if писать будете?))

Comment: Zufir Такой возможности нет

Comment: Вам надо не паузу делать, а засекать время последнего показа.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто как идея. 
Сделаем класс, который будет содержать все, что надо, для проверки и вывода сообщения

```
class PropertyCheckItem
{
    public Func<int> Acessor { get; private set;}
    public int MaxValue  { get; private set;}
    public string Message { get; private set;}

    public PropertyCheckItem(string message, Func<int> acessor, int maxValue)
    {
        Message = message;
        Acessor = acessor;
        MaxValue = maxValue;
    }

    public bool Validate()
    {       
        return !(Acessor() >= MaxValue);        
    }
}
```

Сделаем окно, где будет список таких классов, и этот список будем просто проверять в цикле

```
class MyWnd : Window
{
    List<PropertyCheckItem> _propertyCheckers = new List<PropertyCheckItem>();
    bool closed = false;

    public MyWnd()
    {
        _propertyCheckers.Add(new PropertyCheckItem("Time in SECS more or equals 55!", ()=>DateTime.UtcNow.Second, 55));
        _propertyCheckers.Add(new PropertyCheckItem("Height of window more or equals 500!", ()=>(int)this.Height, 500));        
        _propertyCheckers.Add(new PropertyCheckItem("Width of window more or equals 500!", ()=>(int)this.Width, 500));

        this.Closed+= (sender, args) => closed = true;
        this.Loaded+= (sender, args) => CheckPorps();


    }

    private async void CheckPorps()
    {
        while (!closed)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            foreach (var item in _propertyCheckers)
            {
                if (closed) return;

                if (!item.Validate())
                {
                    if (System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(item.Message, "Caption", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question, MessageBoxResult.Yes) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(2000);
                    }       
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ну и, собственно, всё. Можно добавлять проверки на любое числовое свойство или как то ещё более кастомизировать проверки.

Comment: Получается, что есть зависимость между объектами - то есть пользователь не увидит одновременно все три информационных сообщения

Comment: @FoggyFinder см `Просто как идея`, так как я не имею понятия, что автору надо на самом деле :)